# Counting the right data formats

Tags: java, date-formatting

im stuck at a problem where i need to make a class which counts all the right data formats given to a string.

**Requirement:**
Write a ValidatorDate class that contains the following public countValidData enumeration.

The method will receive as a parameter a string of Strings (String[]) and will return an int representing the number of Strings in the string that respect the format dd/mm/yyyy.

**Signature:**

```
public static int countValidData(String[] words)
```

**Example:**

```
//Your class here
    public class prog {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ValidatorDate.countValidData(new String[]{"Today", "is", "01/04/2019", "01/13/2019",
          "29/02/200s"}));
        // 2
      }
    }
```

and this is what i've done so far

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class ValidatorDate {
    static int numaraDateValide(String[] arrayDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        int counter = 0;
        for (String currentWord : arrayDate) {
            for (int i = currentWord.lastIndexOf("/") + 2; i < currentWord.length() && currentWord.lastIndexOf("/") != -1; i++) {
                try {
                    Date myDate = formatter.parse(currentWord.substring(0, i + 1));
                    counter += 1;
                    i = currentWord.length();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

This code needs a fix, if i introduce for example, the following date: "99/99/9999" it sees it as a valid date, i dont have this "only 12 months" and "30 or 31 days, or 28 in february" implementation, can someone help me with it? Thanks in advance!

**IMPORTANT**

Hey, so on my platform, i am given this example : ""Today", "is", "01/04/2019", "01/13/2019", "29/02/200s" and the solution is 2, the correct answers are 01/04/2019 and 29/02/200s and now i saw that they said "the code will return the number of Strings which START with a correct date and they told me to use SimpleDateFormat, sorry because i missed to say these things.
Probably i need to use SimpleDateFormat because this feature sees "01/04/12m1jf1" as valid

Comment: Use a `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: Can you give me more details please? @Jens

Answer (score 0):

First import as needed

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Now, you can utilize `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`

```
static int countValidData(String[] arrayDate) {
    
        //Initialize SimpleDateFormat
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        formatter.setLenient(false);

        int counter = 0;

        for (String currentWord : arrayDate) {
            
            //Iterate over each possible substring of currentWord
            //Our first substring will end 2 digits after the final "/" in the date
            for (int i = currentWord.lastIndexOf("/")+2; i < currentWord.length() && currentWord.lastIndexOf("/") != -1; i++){
                
                try {
                
                    //Try to convert substring to Date using SimpleDateFormat
                    Date myDate = formatter.parse(currentWord.substring(0,i+1));
                
                    //Increment counter by 1
                    counter += 1;
                    
                    //Stop looping the currentDate
                    i = currentWord.length();
                
                } catch (Exception e){
                    //If an exception was thrown, the date is invalid
                } 
            }
        }

        return counter;
}
```

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    String[] array = new String[3];
    array[0] = "01/04/2019";
    array[1] = "01/13/2019";
    array[2] = "29/02/200s";
    
    System.out.println(countValidData(array));
    
}
```

I also placed `System.out.println(currentWord);` immediately after `counter += 1;` to see which dates are valid

**Output**

```
01/04/2019
29/02/200s
2
```

Comment: Hey, so on my platform, i am given this example : ""Today", "is", "01/04/2019", "01/13/2019",  "29/02/200s" and the solution is 2, the correct answers are 01/04/2019 and 29/02/200s and now i saw that they said "the code will return the number of Strings which START with a correct date and they told me to use SimpleDateFormat, sorry because i missed to say these things.

Comment: Because with SimpleDateFormat, i guess dates that start normally like 01/02/41294sss1 are valid

Comment: Oh ok, just edited my answer, let me know if it works

Comment: Hey, thanks for editing it, it is almost well done but, for example if you put 99/99/9999 which is not supposed to be valid, it is on this code, so it needs just this adjustment.

Comment: Try adding a "formatter.setLenient(false);"

Comment: Thank you sirrrr, it finally worked, appreciate it a lot!!!!!!!